# WHERE Clause in Transform statement in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have the following code

```
TRANSFORM Max(VWDRSSTA.DATUM_ZEIT) AS MaxOfDATUM_ZEIT
SELECT VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER, **Max(VWDRSSTA.DUNKEL) AS DUNKEL** ,    Max(VWDRSSTA.VERS_NR_INT) AS Versicherungsnummer
FROM VWDRSSTA INNER JOIN V_NAMES ON (VWDRSSTA.SYSTEM = V_NAMES.SYSTEM_CODE)    AND (VWDRSSTA.EREIGNIS = V_NAMES.EREIGNIS)
GROUP BY VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER
ORDER BY VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER
PIVOT V_NAMES.MAPPED_NAME;
```

I want the **Max(VWDRSSTA.DUNKEL) AS DUNKEL** to be set as Max(VWDRSSTA.DUNKEL) AS DUNKEL where VWDRSSTA.SYSTEM = VS but it doesn't seem to work. How Will I be able to achieve this? VWDRSSTA is the table name and DUNKEL and SYSTEM are the field names. I want to choose the maximum of Dunkel only for the values of System which as VS. Since it is in a crossTab query. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For a conditional selection in Access you'll need to use `IIF`; IIF simulates a SQL `CASE` statement, which Access doesn't support.

IIF is documented here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3

For your query you'd replace your existing `DUNKEL` select line with something like

```
SELECT
IIF(VWDRSSTA.SYSTEM = 'VS', 
    (SELECT (Max(VWDRSSTA.DUNKEL)) as d FROM VWDRSSTA )
    ,null)
    AS DUNKEL
FROM VWDRSSTA
```

This would select `Max(VWDRSSTA.DUNKEL)` when `SYSTEM` is VS, and leave the field null if not.  If you want a different value for when `SYSTEM` is not VS, just replace the `null` with whatever value you want.  Note the sub-select in the IIF, if you try to get `max()` without the sub-select it'll throw the error questioner mentions in the comments to this answer.  Also note that it will select the max value of `VWDRSSTA.DUNKEL` from the entire table, which I'm not sure is what you want.  If you want the max value by `VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER` that's more complex.

For that you're going to need a different subselect joined into the query, e.g.

```
SELECT 
    vs.ANTRAGSNUMMER, 
    Max(maxget.maxdun) AS DUNKEL,    
    Max(va.VERS_NR_INT) AS Versicherungsnummer
FROM VWDRSSTA as va
INNER JOIN V_NAMES 
    ON (VWDRSSTA.SYSTEM = V_NAMES.SYSTEM_CODE)    
    AND (VWDRSSTA.EREIGNIS = V_NAMES.EREIGNIS)
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT max(DUNKEL) AS maxdun, ANTRAGSNUMMER 
    FROM VWDRSSTA 
    GROUP BY ANTRAGSNUMMER) AS maxget 
    ON va.ANTRAGSNUMMER = maxget.ANTRAGSNUMMER
GROUP BY VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER
ORDER BY VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER
```

Comment: I get an error " You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression ' IIF(VWDRSSTA.SYSTEM = 'VS', Max(VWDRSSTA.DUNKEL), null)' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: I forgot to use a subselect; edited the answer to fix that.  Also added an option to get max by ANTRAGSNUMMER

Comment: I get an error now "Multi-level GROUP BY clause is not allowed in subquery.